# How to create customized quarter based on a given date column sql sql server

Tags: sql, sql-server, date, datetime

I am using Microsoft sql server. I would like to create a customized quarter column based on a given date column. This date column represents the first day of the quarter in that specific year.  The difficulty is my date column has a timespan of 3 years. Each year has different quarter start dates. Below is the example of my date column. Many thanks!

```
Date
2011-02-28 00:00:00:000            ---first date of q1 in 2011
2011-05-31 00:00:00:000            ---first date of q2 in 2011
2011-08-31 00:00:00:000            ---first date of q3 in 2011
2011-12-01 00:00:00:000            ---first date of q4 in 2011
2012-02-29 00:00:00:000            ---first date of q1 in 2012
2012-05-30 00:00:00:000            ---first date of q2 in 2012
2012-08-30 00:00:00:000            ---first date of q3 in 2012
2012-11-30 00:00:00:000            ---first date of q4 in 2012
2013-02-28 00:00:00:000            ---first date of q1 in 2013
2013-05-30 00:00:00:000            ---first date of q2 in 2013
2013-08-30 00:00:00:000            ---first date of q3 in 2013
2013-11-30 00:00:00:000            ---first date of q4 in 2013
```

The expected result would be:

```
Date                               QuarterColumn
2011-02-28 00:00:00:000            q1
2011-05-31 00:00:00:000            q2
2011-08-31 00:00:00:000            q3
2011-12-01 00:00:00:000            q4
2012-02-29 00:00:00:000            q1
2012-05-30 00:00:00:000            q2
2012-08-30 00:00:00:000            q3
2012-11-30 00:00:00:000            q4
2013-02-28 00:00:00:000            q1
2013-05-30 00:00:00:000            q2
2013-08-30 00:00:00:000            q3
2013-11-30 00:00:00:000            q4
```

Comment: And what's your expected result?

Comment: MySQL or SQL Server?

Comment: Um - first day in 2011Q1 is the LAST day of February? While I don't think there are any legal rules about fiscal years (and let's be accurate about what you mean by calendar) I've never seen a quarter start on the last day of any month.

Comment: sql server. In terms of the expected result, please see my updates. thanks

Comment: yes, that's my data and the quarter requirement. need to forget about the calendar/universal quarter rules.

Comment: In that case please untag MySQL.

Comment: Simply add a column to your existing calendar (using Nawaf's solution). If you don't have a calendar table, create it it, it's really usefull.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you need to create lookup table

https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=816974201a48ed0bdf6782c121e1f8db

then you will use this table and join it to using between ( start_q end_q ) to get your customized quarter.

Comment: Those start dates will match two quarters, e.g. `2011-05-31` returns Q1 and Q2. The last row has no `end_q` thus between will fail for dates in that quarter.

Comment: @dnoeth that is right. I think this is a mistake in the logic he should correct start and end for each quarter to get the desired result.

Comment: No, you should change the logic in your query, decrease the date returned by LEAD :-)

Comment: @dnoeth check plz
https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=816974201a48ed0bdf6782c121e1f8db

Answer (score 0):

For SQL SERVER

> ```
> CREATE TABLE datetable (
>   [id] VARCHAR(11),
>   [Date] datetime
> );
>
> INSERT INTO datetable
>   ([id], [Date])
> VALUES
>   ('1', '2011-02-28 00:00:00:000'),
>   ('2', '2011-05-31 00:00:00:000'),
>   ('3', '2011-08-31 00:00:00:000'),
>   ('4', '2011-12-01 00:00:00:000'),
>   ('5', '2012-02-29 00:00:00:000'),
>   ('6', '2012-05-30 00:00:00:000'),
>   ('7', '2012-08-30 00:00:00:000'),
>   ('8', '2012-11-30 00:00:00:000'),
>   ('9', '2013-02-28 00:00:00:000'),
>   ('10', '2013-05-30 00:00:00:000'),
>   ('11','2013-08-30 00:00:00:000'),
>   (12,'2013-11-30 00:00:00:000');
> GO
> ```
>
> ```
> 12 rows affected
> ```

> ```
> SELECT CONCAT('Q',DATEPART(quarter,[Date]), ' ',DATEPART(year,[Date]))
>               FROM
>               datetable
>                                             ORDER BY [Date]
> GO
> ```
>
> ```
> | (No column name) |
> | :--------------- |
> | Q1 2011          |
> | Q2 2011          |
> | Q3 2011          |
> | Q4 2011          |
> | Q1 2012          |
> | Q2 2012          |
> | Q3 2012          |
> | Q4 2012          |
> | Q1 2013          |
> | Q2 2013          |
> | Q3 2013          |
> | Q4 2013          |
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=838809eeb15e3da26fb6b00994032025)*

FOR mysql

**Schema (MySQL v5.6)**

```
CREATE TABLE datetable (
  `id` VARCHAR(11),
  `Date` datetime
);

INSERT INTO datetable
  (`id`, `Date`)
VALUES
  ('1', '2011-02-28 00:00:00:000'),
  ('2', '2011-05-31 00:00:00:000'),
  ('3', '2011-08-31 00:00:00:000'),
  ('4', '2011-12-01 00:00:00:000'),
  ('5', '2012-02-29 00:00:00:000'),
  ('6', '2012-05-30 00:00:00:000'),
  ('7', '2012-08-30 00:00:00:000'),
  ('8', '2012-11-30 00:00:00:000'),
  ('9', '2013-02-28 00:00:00:000'),
  ('10', '2013-05-30 00:00:00:000'),
  ('11','2013-08-30 00:00:00:000'),
  (12,'2013-11-30 00:00:00:000');
```

---

**Query #1**

```
SELECT CONCAT('Q',QUARTER(`Date`), ' ',YEAR(`Date`))
FROM
  datetable
ORDER BY `Date`;

| CONCAT('Q',QUARTER(`Date`), ' ',YEAR(`Date`)) |
| --------------------------------------------- |
| Q1 2011                                       |
| Q2 2011                                       |
| Q3 2011                                       |
| Q4 2011                                       |
| Q1 2012                                       |
| Q2 2012                                       |
| Q3 2012                                       |
| Q4 2012                                       |
| Q1 2013                                       |
| Q2 2013                                       |
| Q3 2013                                       |
| Q4 2013                                       |
```

---

[View on DB Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/2yKt6d5RWngXVYJKPGZL6m/7)